# ¿Cómo llamo un archivo de audio de res con un ToggleButton?

Tags: java, android-studio

Estoy un poco enredado. Quiero que el ToggleButton active una música cuando esté en ON y la desactive cuando esté en OFF. Ya cree un service y coloqué el audio en la carpeta **raw de res** pero no sé cómo llamarlo del main. adjunto el código. Gracias de antemano.

```
public class ActivityInicio extends AppCompatActivity {

private ToggleButton musica;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_inicio);

    final ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.boton);
    toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
           // if (isChecked) {
                // The toggle is enabled


           // } else {
                // The toggle is disabled
            }



    });

}

public void  play(View view){
    //Reproducir musica
    Intent i= new Intent(this, MyServiceMusica.class);
    startService(i);

}

public void stop(View view){
    //Detener musica
    Intent i= new Intent(this, MyServiceMusica.class);
    stopService(i);
}

}
```

Comment: play() y stop() funcionan? Que es el parametro view?